# How to find the closest IP from a list of IPs?

Tags: javascript, networking, ip, protocols

I want to know if that's possible

I have one **given** IP, example: **191.184.222.43** (public ipv4)

And I have a Loong list of other IP addresses, example:

[ ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4 ... and so on ]

Now I have to find which IP of my list i'ts closest (physically) to my **given** IP (**191.184.222.43**)

Is it that possible? Or am I thinking differently

Comment: Considering you can't pinpoint an exact location for an IP address but rather a proximation/area, this is near impossible to do on a very precise level.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need to be precise

Comment: While you can use some API to geolocate your given IP up to certain city/area, you can not (within reasonable period of time) locate **all** the IP's located in the same city/area. Besides, IP's leased at any given moment by mobile devices will be geolocated to operators head office, which would be so not true for large countries and mobile operators having country-wide coverage.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many API's that can accomplish this one example of one is over at https://ipstack.com/ . It geolocates based on IP and with some parsing you can easily accomplish this!

[image: ipstack.com]

Example Code:

```
// set endpoint and your access key
var ip = '134.201.250.155'
var access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY';

// get the API result via jQuery.ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        // output the "capital" object inside "location"
        alert(json.location.capital);

    }
});
```

Example Output (JSON):

```
[
  {
    "ip": "134.201.250.155",
    "type": "ipv4",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "region_code": "CA",
    "region_name": "California",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "zip": "90013",
    "latitude": 34.0453,
    "longitude": -118.2413,
    "location": { ... },
    "time_zone": { ... },
    "currency": { ... },
    "connection": { ... },
  }
]
```